# Replacing specific values in an array based on logic

Tags: arrays, matlab, math, octave, modulo

I'm trying to replace the values in **array1** following this Logic:

1. If the values are greater than one use just the decimal value.
2. If it's exactly 1 stay at 1
3. If 0 stay 0
4. If neg make positive and follow the logic

The code I used was:

```
array1=[0.5 1.3 1.0 0.0 -0.2 -2.78]
array1(array1>1)=mod(abs(array1),1)
```

what I expected to get is `array1 = [0.5 0.3 1.0 0.0 0.2 0.78]`

But I get an **error: =: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 1x1, op2 is 1x5)** how can I fix this?

PS: I'm using Octave 5.2 which is similar to Matlab

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This causes an *Unable to perform assignment*-error because left and right side of the assignment differ in size: You need to use the logical indexing on both sides `array1>1`.

```matlab
array1=[0.5 1.3 1.0 0.0 -0.2]
% create logical vector for indexing
lg = array1 > 1
% replace elements
array1(lg) = mod( abs(array1(lg)) ,1)
```

This should work in MATLAB + Octave.
You can also split the different operations :

```matlab
% ensure positiveness
array1 = abs(array1);
% force to one
lg = array1 > 1;
array1(lg) = mod(array(1),1);
```

this returns
`array1 =  0.5000    0.3000    1.0000         0    0.20`

If you absolutely want to stick to your approach, you can use a little trick: add `+1e-10` to the second input of the `mod` function to let `1` "survive" the operation ;)

```matlab
array1 = mod( abs(array1) ,1+1e-10)
```

This trick will yield slightly different results because the modulus is `1.0000000001` and not `1`. The error will be higher, the higher the input number. However, from your example-array I would guess that this risk could be OK.

Comment: I don't understand why you've suggested the OP wants a solution different to what they've specifically defined in the 2nd half of your answer? And your "trick" gives a different (albeit only slightly) output by not using mod base 1. This is a correct answer up until the first code block then I think it needs a bit of thought!

Comment: @Wolfie ok I just wanted to give him/her credit since he/her got me where I needed to get to.

Comment: @Wolfie thx, I adjusted it raised a word of warning to the "tick" ;)

Answer (score 1):

max's answer got me where I needed to get to here's what I used.

```
array1=[0.5 1.3 1.0 0.0 -0.2 -2.63]

array1=abs(array1) %1) make array positive
lg = array1 > 1 %2) create logical vector for indexing
array1(lg) = mod( abs(array1(lg)) ,1) %3) replace elements
```

- 

```
array1 =

   0.50000   1.30000   1.00000   0.00000  -0.20000  -2.63000

array1 =

   0.50000   1.30000   1.00000   0.00000   0.20000   2.63000

lg =

  0  1  0  0  0  1

array1 =

   0.50000   0.30000   1.00000   0.00000   0.20000   0.63000
```